# Show Ruby count result as html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have created a custom method that will return unique items, together with the number of occurrences in a table. I have the following code:

```
@answers = Answer.all.count(:group => 'answer')
```

The result is fine when rendering it to JSON, showing:

```
{"0,0":1,"1,2":1,"2,2":1,"3,3":1}
```

...but I am unable to render the result to html. I can not display the key, values:

```
<% @answers.each do |answer| %>
  <tr>
    <td>key: <%= @answer.??? %></td>
    <td>value: <%= @answer.??? %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What does @answers tell you when you "pp @answers" on the rails console? And is it indeed a Hash as user1284966 suggests? "pp @answers.class". Also, the call to `all` seems redundand to me, as `count(:group => 'foo')` already implies the all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If answers is a hash (and it looks like it is) you can pass the key and value into the rendering block by using two parameters instead of one.

like this:

```
<% @answers.each do |key, val| %>
  <tr>
    <td>key: <%= key %></td>
    <td>value: <%= val %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```